# Moving from hyrbrid Azure to full cloud

Tags: azure, migration

I have a small hybrid infrastructure that I am trying to move to full cloud. We already have an Azure instance configured and have moved our machines into the cloud as virtual machines (including our domain controllers).

We are currently syncing:

- On prem AD through AD connect to Azure AD
- On prem firewall which is also acting as our vpn gateway

Everything else has been moved and is fully reliant on Azure including:

- Azure virtual firewall which contains the same rules as the on prem firewall
- All servers and VM's in our environment
- Network configurations (we have a switch in office as well which may be syncing)

I don't have much experience with cloud migrations, and I read that removing some of these on prem connections could mess up certain things (like user profiles on domain joined laptops for instance). I need to get the firewall and vpn into Azure as well as sever the connection between Azure AD and on prem AD without breaking too much. Any advice or things to watch out for as I get the info for this conversion together would be appreciated. I'd love to answer any questions anyone may have.

I haven't tried anything yet.